# Do we need to deploy binaries + (pdb files + xml file)?

Tags: deployment, binary, bin

When deploying our .NET application (consisting of web and WCF services) do we need all files from the bin folder including the pdb debug files amd xml ) or will the binaries suffice ?  We dont need to debug to the server.

At the moment we have binaries like system.web.helpers.dll as well as the system.web.helpers.xml

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need .pdb files if you don't need debugger info